# How to get an element of type list by index

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, variadic-templates, c++20

How can an element of a type list `using L = type_list<T1, T2, ...>` be retrieved by index, like [std::tuple_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element), preferrably in a non recursive way?

I want to avoid using tuples as type lists for use cases, that require instantiation for passing a list like `f(L{})`.

```
template<typename...> struct type_list {};
using L = typelist<int, char, float, double>;
using T = typeAt<2, L>; // possible use case
```

Not sure if an *iteration* using [std::index_sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) and a test via [std::is_same](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)  of the `std::integral_constant` version of the index is a good aproach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to avoid using tuples as type lists for use cases, that require
> instantiation for passing a list like `f(L{})`

If you don't want to instanciate `std::tuple` but you're ok with it in
unevaluated contexts, you may take advantage of `std::tuple_element` to
implement your `typeAt` trait:

```
template <std::size_t I, typename T>
struct typeAt;

template <std::size_t I, typename... Args>
struct typeAt<I, type_list<Args...>> : std::tuple_element<I, std::tuple<Args...>> {};
                                    // ^ let library authors do the work for you

using L = type_list<int, char, float, double>;
using T = typename typeAt<2, L>::type;

static_assert(std::is_same<T, float>::value, "");
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html), this is a one-liner (as always):

```cpp
template<typename...> struct type_list {};
using L = typelist<int, char, float, double>;
using T = mp_at_c<L, 2>; // <==
```

Note that this will compile significantly more efficiently than using `tuple_element`. On clang, the implementation even uses a compiler intrinsic.

Answer (score 1):

You might re-implement a simplified non-recursive tuple-like version if you don't want to use `std::tuple`:

```
template <std::size_t I, typename T>
struct type_list_leaf
{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T> struct tag{ using type = T; };

template <typename Seq, typename...>
struct type_list_impl;

template <std::size_t... Is, typename... Ts>
struct type_list_impl<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...> : type_list_leaf<Is, Ts>...
{
};

template <std::size_t I, typename T>
tag<T> type_list_element_tag(const type_list_leaf<I, T>&);

template <std::size_t I, typename Tuple>
using tuple_element = decltype(type_list_element_tag<I>(std::declval<Tuple>()));

template <std::size_t I, typename Tuple>
using tuple_element_t = typename tuple_element<I, Tuple>::type;

template <typename ... Ts>
using type_list = type_list_impl<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>, Ts...>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dvd8K33Ec)